# Outlook file tab is orange

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I logged on to my PC and now every time I open an email it goes straight to the file tab not the message tab, and it is showing as being orange, which it wasn't yesterday.

Please advise what I need to do to change it,

Answer (score 0):

The file tab is always orange in Outlook 2010. Maybe you've just minimized the ribbon menu. Open a message and press `ctrl + F1`. Then the ribbon should appear in the normal form again,  so you don't have to press the message tab to open up the ribbon menu anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your ribbon menu might have gotten "unpinned".  Try clicking on the "pin" icon (shaped like a thumb tack or push pin).  This will keep your ribbon bar open along the top.